# Applying a xalan java transformation to an axis2 object?

Tags: java, apache-axis, xalan

I am tying to get the open source OWL-S API http://on.cs.unibas.ch/owls-api/ to use axis2. I have managed to get the requests sent correctly but when it comes to the response I am having trouble applying a transformation to it. In order to make my question easier to answer I am providing some standalone code which should run without having to import the project. To setup the DOMSource:

```
String xmlString = "<ns1:countResponse xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.test.de/pill-counter\"><ns1:value>0</ns1:value><ns1:value>0</ns1:value><ns1:value>1</ns1:value><ns1:value>0</ns1:value><ns1:value>0</ns1:value><ns1:value>0</ns1:value></ns1:countResponse>";
    ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());
    OMElement test = null;
    try {
        StAXBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(xmlStream);
        test = (OMElement) builder.getDocument().getChildren().next();

    } catch (XMLStreamException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    OMElement documentElement = null;
      try {
        documentElement = AXIOMUtil.stringToOM(DOOMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory(), xmlString);
    } catch (XMLStreamException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

     SAAJConverterFactory convFactory = (SAAJConverterFactory) FactoryRegistry.getFactory(org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.factory.SAAJConverterFactory.class);
     SAAJConverter conv = convFactory.getSAAJConverter();


     //Create soap 1.1 message
    SOAPMessage msg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
    SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope se = sp.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody soapBody = se.getBody();
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory soapFactory = javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory.newInstance();
    response = conv.toSAAJ(documentElement, soapBody, soapFactory);
    Node root = response;
```

And now to apply the transformation:

```
Transformer transformer = null;
    try {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.test.de/pill-counter\">\n\n\t<xsl:template match=\"/\">\n\t\t<xsl:value-of select=\"sum(*/ns1:value)\" />\n\t</xsl:template>\n</xsl:stylesheet>")));
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(root), new StreamResult(System.out));
    } catch (TransformerException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result of running this code is a NullPointerException.

```
SystemId unknown; Line num.0; Column num.0; java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tried searching for a solution to this problem on Google, the Xalan-j mailing list and on this site with no luck. I have also tried with several other coding approaches and no luck. Any ideas from anyone?

I found another way to get this working by generating the Document from scratch:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }          
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(documentElement.toString()));
    Document document = null;
    try{
        document=db.parse(is);
    } catch (SAXException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add information about the Axis2 and Axiom version that you are using?

Comment: Hi, I am using the latest axis version axis2-1.6.1 and axiom 1.2.12, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I edited my answer so that it applies to Axiom 1.2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the JAXP API on an Axiom tree you don't need to convert it first to SAAJ or DOM. Axiom is able to create a SAXSource that can be passed to JAXP. An example can be found [here](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/quickstart-samples.html#Schema_validation_using_javax.xml.validation). That example uses the `javax.xml.validation` API, but for `javax.xml.transform` it works the same way.

Note that the example uses some APIs introduced in recent Axiom versions, but the feature already exists for quite some time. Depending on the Axiom version you are using, the code needs to be adapted to the older API. In particular, instead of calling `getSAXSource` (which was introduced in 1.2.13), you need to construct an `org.apache.axiom.om.impl.jaxp.OMSource` object and pass that to JAXP.

Comment: Hi, you are right the code works without exception if I call the transformer like this:  `transformer.transform(new OMSource(documentElement), new StreamResult(System.out));`    I am one step closer but the output is not what I would expect it is just **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>1**

Comment: Versus the correct output: **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>001000**

Comment: I made an edit to the original question with the code that generates the correct output. Going through the AXIOM API it says that the SAX content handler must be aware of the namespace mapping for the ns prefix. The namespace mapping is done automatically added by AXIOM but maybe there is something I am still missing to get this to work. Thank you very much for your further help with this.

Comment: I don't understand. Given that your stylesheet basically evaluates sum(*/ns1:value), the correct result is "1" not "001000". Anyway, with both methods (Axiom or DOM) I get the same result, namely "1". Are you sure that you used the same stylesheet in both tests?

Comment: I used the same stylesheet on both tests, and you are right. Maybe I formulated the question wrong. The result is different for DOM if you call `transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement()), new StreamResult(System.out));` than just `transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));` is there a way to _get the documentElement_ in AXIOM? I tried with    `transformer.transform(new OMSource(documentElement.getBuilder().getDocumentElement()), new StreamResult(System.out));` and nothing.

Comment: I tested that with the XSLT implementation from Java 1.6, and the result in both cases (`new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement()` and `new DOMSource(document)`) is the same. Note that according to the XSLT specs, the input for a transformation is always a document. Therefore I would expect that if one passes an element to the XSLT processor, it will implicitly create a document for it, and this is what happens with the XSLT implementation in Java 1.6. Maybe you are using another XSLT implementation (such as Saxon)?

Comment: I am running Java build 1.6.0_29-b11, I checked with the debugger and the transformer object is `org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl@3325070` I tried with `document.getDocumentElement()` and without and the result is different for me. Anyways, I think your initial answer was dead on. Thank you very much for your help, it is the first time I post a question and really receieved a lot of help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using wsdl2java to construct stubs, rather that using the low-level API directly? This would let you easily manipulate the reponse in java. Using xslt seems like an unusual approach in this case.

Comment: The way the code I am using works I am stuck with the low-level API